# Ведь это его перу(,) перу Соловина(,) принадлежит добрая половина написанных заявлений

Tags: пунктуация

Скажите, пожалуйста, как верно расставить знаки препинания в следующем предложении и почему так:

*Ведь это его перу(,) перу Соловина(,) принадлежит добрая половина написанных заявлений...*

У Розенталя есть такое:
Уточняющие определения могут конкретизировать общее значение местоимений этот, тот, такой, каждый, один (в значении местоимения) и т. п.

Применимо ли? И нужно ли тогда обособление с двух сторон?
Или же это пояснительное определение и следовательно требуется лишь одна запятая перед?

Answer (score 1):

Конечно, нужны 2 запятые.
Дело в том, что здесь уточняющее дополнение (существительное), а не определение (прилагательное), поэтому нужны 2 запятые, а не 1.

Правило Розенталя такое:
Обособляется распространенное приложение, выраженное нарицательным существительным с зависимыми словами и относящееся к нарицательному существительному (обычно такое приложение стоит после определяемого слова, реже — впереди него).
http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=111

У Розенталя имеется ещё и такая специфическая структура:
*Ведь это его перу — перу Соловина принадлежит добрая половина написанных заявлений...*
Она может быть очень кстати, если после "Соловина" не задумывается пауза.

Comment: Дайте, пожалуйста, ссылку на "специфическую конструкцию" у Розенталя. Немного сомнительно. Я смог найти только про "вставную конструкцию" (что смотрелось бы естественней в этой ситуации), но там два тире.

Comment: Посмотрите, пожалуйста, §46.1 [у Розенталя](http://evartist.narod.ru/text1/31.htm).

Comment: Да мне так нравится — цифрами, таким образом количество выделяется в тексте, ну и как сокращение. Конструкция — по ссылке, даже в двух пунктах (подряд), между которыми разницы не заметил — думаю, что её и нет.

Comment: Даёшь SMS-орфографию в массы!  :/

Comment: Вас не затруднит сказать точнее номера тех пунктов, на которые Вы ссылаетесь? Я даже не для себя спрашиваю, а для удобства всех пользователей. Ведь не каждый сможет потратить достаточно времени, чтобы угадать, между какими именно пунктами по Вашему мнению нет разницы. Вы имеете в виду п.10.3 и какие-то исключения из него?

Comment: Оно больше к оформлению текста относится, а не к орфографии. После того как напечатал это предложение, даже у Розенталя увидел "Способы **оформления**". П. №2.10 примечания 2), 3). То есть между пунктами примечания.

Comment: Просто §19.10.3? (Там нет никакого 2.10, а в §19.10 примечания есть только к подпункту 3.) Если так, тогда понятно. Вряд ли эти примечания можно отнести к нашему случаю. Но сам пункт Вы выбрали верно и по нему выделение должно быть с двух сторон.

Comment: Ладно. Пункт 2 => примечание 10 => пункт 3 => примечания 2 и 3 (просто изначально неверно подумал, что последние примечания относятся ко всему примечанию 10). Интонационно оно совпадает с примерами Розенталя, и конкретизация имеет место. В случае с одним тире уточнения нет, есть лишь отождествление с тем, что конкретнее и важнее, чем первое понятие, и продолжает мысль. Здесь в этом есть смысл.